# Warning : Not mapping found with URI in dispatcher servlet

Tags: spring

Controller is :

```
package com.project.controller;


import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.project.model.User;
import com.project.service.UserService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/testmap")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<User> testMethod(){
        try{
            System.out.println("--------------inside testmethod----------------------------");
            return userService.getAllUser();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Occur = "+e);
            return null;
        }


    }

}
```

Service is look like :

```
package com.project.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import com.project.dao.UserDAO;
import com.project.model.User;

@Service
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
      return userDAO.fetchAll(User.class);
    }

}
```

DAO is look like :

```
 package com.project.dao;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

    import com.project.common.HibernateUtil;

    @Repository
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class UserDAO extends HibernateUtil {

    }
```

Generic DAO is :

```
package com.project.common;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Repository
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class HibernateUtil {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public <T> Serializable create(final T entity) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);        
    }

    public <T> T update(final T entity) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(entity);   
        return entity;
    }

    public <T> void delete(final T entity) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }

    public <T> void delete(Serializable id, Class<T> entityClass) {
        T entity = fetchById(id, entityClass);
        delete(entity);
    }

    public <T> void saveOrUpdate(final T o){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(o);
      }

    public <T> List<T> getAll(final Class<T> type) {
        final Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(type);
        return crit.list();
      }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
    public <T> List<T> fetchAll(Class<T> entityClass) {        
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(" FROM "+entityClass.getName()).list();        
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public <T> List fetchAll(String query) {        
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query).list();        
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T fetchById(Serializable id, Class<T> entityClass) {
        return (T)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(entityClass, id);
    }   
}
```

web.xml is :

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

rest-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service, 
        DAO -->
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.project" />

    <!-- Getting Database properties -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- View Resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- DataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driverClass}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />

        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${connection.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${connection.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${connection.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${connection.maxIdleTime}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.project.model"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

my project configuration is above. Actually the problem is that no mapping found for 'http://localhost:8080/ShoppingProject/testmap/test' and warning is below

```
2017-06-24 13:19:39 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:865 - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/ShoppingProject/testmap/test]
2017-06-24 13:19:39 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:310 - Looking up handler method for path /testmap/test
2017-06-24 13:19:39 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:320 - Did not find handler method for [/testmap/test]
2017-06-24 13:19:39 WARN  PageNotFound:1147 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ShoppingProject/testmap/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
2017-06-24 13:19:39 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
```

I am stuck with what is problem in mapping? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you post your full stack !

Comment: I have already post full stack....